# nfs export external harddrive

Tags: nfs, fedora, fuse

I am trying to export my external harddrive using nfs. The external harddrive has the filesystem of type fuseblk. Does nfs export support fuseblk type? if not is there any other way that I can mount this?

```
Filesystem                        Type     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                            rootfs    52324100  14747588  34955072  30% /
devtmpfs                          devtmpfs   1539012         0   1539012   0% /dev
tmpfs                             tmpfs      1547620       344   1547276   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             tmpfs      1547620      2588   1545032   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vg_deepwaters-lv_root ext4      52324100  14747588  34955072  30% /
tmpfs                             tmpfs      1547620         0   1547620   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                             tmpfs      1547620         0   1547620   0% /media
/dev/sda1                         ext4        508644     99540    383504  21% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_deepwaters-lv_home ext4      60016356  28404568  28605324  50% /home
/dev/sdb1                         fuseblk  976760000 390502480 586257520  40% /run/media/kamal/Iomega HDD
```

And I see the following error when I restart nfs server

```
Jul 12 19:49:10 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' (using servicehelper)
Jul 12 19:49:10 deepwaters dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.PackageKit' (using servicehelper)
Jul 12 19:49:10 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jul 12 19:49:10 deepwaters dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.PackageKit'
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' (using servicehelper)
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus[823]: [system] Activating service name='net.reactivated.Fprint' (using servicehelper)
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: Launching FprintObject
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus[823]: [system] Successfully activated service 'net.reactivated.Fprint'
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: D-Bus service launched with name: net.reactivated.Fprint
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: entering main loop
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: user 'root' claiming the device: 0
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: now monitoring fd 10
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: device 0 claim status 0
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: no longer monitoring fd 10
Jul 12 19:53:01 deepwaters dbus-daemon[823]: ** Message: released device 0
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters rpc.mountd[3356]: Caught signal 15, un-registering and exiting.
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters systemd[1]: Unit nfs-mountd.service entered failed state.
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters kernel: [347213.878817] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters exportfs[4344]: exportfs: /run/media/kamal/Iomega HDD/nfs does not support NFS export
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters kernel: [347213.986080] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Jul 12 19:53:06 deepwaters kernel: [347213.986094] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the space in the name of the drive(Iomega HDD). After removing the space it is mounting fine without any issues.